# Create comparator for inserting triplets in min priority queue

Tags: c++

I have made a triplet using a class with all members as integers. I want to insert the triplet in min priority queue using STL in C++. I heard that it can be done using a bool comparator function, but don't have any idea about how to use it with 3 elements.

Note: I don't want to use vector pairs for inserting 3 values (I know how to do it ), I only want to use class triplets.
Can someone help me in implementing it?

```
using namespace std;

#include<bits/stdc++.h>

class triplet{
    public:
    int element;
    int arrIndex;
    int elementIndex;
};

    priority_queue<triplet, vector<triplet>, greater<triplet>> pq;
```

Comment: What is the order of comparing? Do we compare `element` first, then `arrIndex`, then `arrIndex` ?

Comment: Compare on the basis of the element ( triplet .element ). Smaller element comes first . Just like min heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don`t know why you did std::vector, std::greater but.

```
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
class triplet {
public:
    int element;
    int arrIndex;
    int elementIndex;

    constexpr bool operator>(const triplet& r)
    {
        return element > r.element;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::priority_queue<triplet, std::vector<triplet>, std::greater<>> queue;
    triplet a, b;
    a.element = 3;
    b.element = 5;
    queue.push(a);
    queue.push(b);
}
```

This is possible by define a triplet operator.

or

```
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
class triplet {
public:
    int element;
    int arrIndex;
    int elementIndex;
};

template <>
struct std::greater<triplet>
{
    bool operator()(const triplet& l, const triplet& r)
    {
        return l.element > r.element;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::priority_queue<triplet, std::vector<triplet>, std::greater<triplet>> queue;
    triplet a, b;
    a.element = 3;
    b.element = 5;
    queue.push(a);
    queue.push(b);
}
```

through template specialization.